# What is alternative to Assembly.GetTypes() in windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Assembly.GetTypes() is working in WP8.0 but when coming to Wp8.1 it shows error.How can i solve it

```
   foreach (var tp in Assembly.GetTypes())
   {
     //Statements
   }
```

Comment: And why are you using `Assembly.GetTypes` in the first place? And what assembly is it you're querying?

Answer (score 0):

In WinRT (Windows 8/8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 XAML) you can use

```
foreach (var type in (typeof(MainViewModel).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.DefinedTypes)
{
    ...
}
```

Where MainViewModel is any class from the assembly you want to query.